# How do I use update_option to give me a new option name each time a form is submitted?

Tags: database, wordpress

How do I use update_option to give me a new option name each time a form is submitted? The code I'm using now overwrites the database value. Instead I need to have a new address saved each time.

The code:

```
                        // assign addrss to var
                        $address = esc_html( $_POST['address'] );

                        //assign JSON object to var using geocodeing function('address') input 
                        $address_results = boj_gmap_geocode($address);

                        // transfer data to options array
                        $options['py_name'] = $py_username;
                        $options['address'] = $address;
                        $options['coords']  = $address_results;

                        // create and name the option_name and set fields with $options array
                        update_option( 'py_menu_item', $options );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unique key by appending e.g. `$py_username`:

```
update_option( 'py_menu_item_' . sanitize_key( $py_username ), $options );
```

Comment: did the trick beautifully. Now I have a unique key each time. Perfect!